# Form a list using prime numbers

Tags: code-golf, math, number, primes, division

You have been given N piles of coins. You have decided to divide each of those B<sub>1</sub>, B<sub>2</sub>, ..., B<sub>N</sub> piles among separate groups of people. The amount of people receiving coins has to be a prime number and the amount of money given to each person must be different in each pile.

Input: N, B<sub>1</sub>, B<sub>2</sub>, ..., B<sub>N</sub> (The amount of coins in each individual pile).

Output: NP<sub>1</sub>, NP<sub>2</sub>, ..., NP<sub>N</sub> with NP being the number of people(prime number) receiving the coins. If this is impossible then yield some unachievable result (like `0`, `-1`, `None`, `[]`, or `"impossible"`) or raise an error.

Example:

```
3
7 8 9
```

Output: `7 2 3`

Because 7 is the only prime number that can divide 7 evenly, the same for 8 and 2 and 9 and 3. Also, notice that (7 / 7 = 1) ≠ (8 / 2 = 4) ≠ (9 / 3 = 3).

Comment: `N` is a redundant input, may we forego taking it?

Comment: May we yield some other non-achievable result (e.g. `0`, an empty list, a string like "impossible", or raise an error) for impossible cases? (I'd actually recommend only valid input, or allowing undefined behaviour in such cases, but it's up to you.)

Comment: You may forego the input of N. And yes to the second question.

Comment: So, the lowest prime divisor of each number?

Comment: @totallyhuman not quite - if the input were say `[7,8,8]` it would be impossible (since using `2` for both `8` results in two `4`s.) Furthermore, if the input were say `[7,30,30]` then `[7,2,2]` would be invalid but `[7,2,3]` and `[7,3,2]` amongst others would work.

Comment: ...And the lowest non-1 divisor of a number is always prime.

Comment: @JonathanAllan So it's lowest non-1 divisor of each and if the list contains only unique elements.

Comment: @totallyhuman no - the output for `[7,8,16]` may ONLY be `[7,2,2]` - this list does not only contain unique elements (it's the division results that must be unique).

Comment: Why doesn't `{5, 11, 2}` work for your example of 3 piles with 7, 8, and 9 coins in each?  That gives 24 coins to divide up. Correct?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 13 bytes

```
Ò.»â€˜ʒ÷DÙQ}θ
```

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASkA1v8wNWFiMWX//8OSLsK7w6LigqzLnMqSw7dEw5lRfc64//9bNyw4LDEyXQ)**

A port of my Pyth answer.

- `Ò` gets the prime fact**Ò**rs of each.
- `.»` folds a dyadic command, `â` (c**â**rtesi**â**n product) between each two elements in the list from right to left with opposite right/left operands.
- `€˜` flattens **€**ach.
- `ʒ...}` filt**ʒ**rs those which satisfy the following condition:

  - `÷` pairwise integer division with the input.
  - `D` **D**uplicate (pushes two copies of the item to the stack).
  - `Ù` removes duplicate elements, keeping a **Ù**niq**Ù**e occurrence of each element.
  - `Q` checks for e**Q**uality.
- `θ` gets the last element.

Answer (score 4):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly),  <s>15</s>  14 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
³:ŒQẠ
ÆfŒpÇÐfṪ
```

A full-program which accepts one argument, a list of numbers, and prints a representation of another list of numbers, or `0` if the task is impossible.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASkA1v9qZWxsef//wrM6xZJR4bqgCsOGZsWScMOHw5Bm4bmq////WzcsOCw5XQ)**

#### How?

```
³:ŒQẠ - Link 1, unique after division?: list of primes, Ps   e.g. [7,2,2]  or  [7,3,3]
³     - program's first input                                e.g. [7,8,8]  or  [7,9,30]
 :    - integer division by Ps                                    [1,4,4]      [1,3,10]
  ŒQ  - distinct sieve                                            [1,1,0]      [1,1,1]
    Ạ - all truthy?                                               0            1

ÆfŒpÇÐfṪ - Main link: list of coin stack sizes, Bs   e.g. [7,8,12]
Æf       - prime factorisation (vectorises)               [[7],[2,2,2],[2,2,3]]
  Œp     - Cartesian product                              [[7,2,2],[7,2,2],[7,2,3],[7,2,2],[7,2,2],[7,2,3],[7,2,2],[7,2,2],[7,2,3]]
     Ðf  - filter keep if:
    Ç    -   call last link (1) as a monad                 1       1       0       1       1       0       1       1       0
         -                                                [[7,2,2],[7,2,2],[7,2,2],[7,2,2],[7,2,2],[7,2,2]]
       Ṫ - tail (note: tailing an empty list yields 0)    [7,2,2]
         - implicit print
```

Comment: +1 Haha, I think `µ⁼Q` would work as an alternative to the fancy distinct sieve, but good job!

Answer (score 2):

## [Pyth](https://pyth.readthedocs.io), 15 bytes

```
ef{I/VQT.nM*FPM
```

**[Try it here!](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=ef%7BI%2FVQT.nM%2aFPM&input=%5B7%2C8%2C12%5D&debug=0)**

#### How?

```
ef{I/VQT.nM*FPM | Full program, which foregoes the size.
                |
             PM | Prime factorisation of each integer.
           *F   | Fold Cartesian Product over the list of primes.
        .nM     | Flatten each.
 f              | Filter.
  {I/VQT        | Filter condition (uses a variable T).
    /V          | Vectorised integer division...
      QT        | Over the input and the current item.
  {I            | Is invariant over deduplication (removing duplicates)?
e               | Take the last element.
                | Output the result implicitly.
```